# Laravel Middleware is returning null in authenticated user

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to prevent some users from accessing to some routes. I have created a middleware called CheckUserRole. But I always get a null response when I try to fetch any data from the logged-in user, unlike when, for example, I request the user's ID in a view.

I'm using PHP 8.2.8 And laravel 10

This is my web.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PsychologicalTestController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProfileController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TaskController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CapsuleController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::redirect('/', '/login');

// Authentication routes
Route::middleware(['auth',])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () { 

    // Admin routes
    Route::middleware(['check.user.role'])->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::resource('psycological-test', PsychologicalTestController::class);
        Route::resource('profile', ProfileController::class);
        Route::resource('task', TaskController::class, ['as' => 'admin']);
        Route::resource('capsule', CapsuleController::class);
    });

});
```

To my greater surprise, I decided to include only the Auth middleware and try to break it with a dd, but upon executing a view, it would open normally, as if it weren't entering the middleware.

Test in my web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
        Route::resource('capsule', CapsuleController::class);
    });
});
```

App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php

```
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     */
    protected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
    {
        dd($request);
        // return $request->expectsJson() ? null : route('login');
    }
```

I tried moving the middleware in the kernel file, but doesn't worked.

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserRole::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckParticipantPhase::class,
        
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's middleware aliases.
     *
     * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware to routes and groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'precognitive' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'check.user.role' =>\App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserRole::class,
        'check.participant.phase' =>\App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserStatus::class,
        'localize'                => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,
        'localizationRedirect'    => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
        'localeSessionRedirect'   => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class,
        'localeCookieRedirect'    => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleCookieRedirect::class,
        'localeViewPath'          => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationViewPath::class
    ];
}
```

Finally, when i run this

```
dd(
 auth()->id() ?? '?',
 Auth::id() ?? '?',
 $request->user()->id ?? '?',
 auth()->check(),
 get_class(auth()->guard())
);
```

i got this

```
"?" // app/Http/Middleware/CheckUserRole.php:19
"?" // app/Http/Middleware/CheckUserRole.php:19
"?" // app/Http/Middleware/CheckUserRole.php:19
false // app/Http/Middleware/CheckUserRole.php:19
"Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard" // app/Http/Middleware/CheckUserRole.php:19
```

Any hint or help will be appreciated.

Comment: when you run that where? if you are talking about in `redirectTo` that only gets called when the user is not authenticated so those values dumped are correct

Comment: When i run it on `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
        Route::resource('capsule', CapsuleController::class);
    });
}); `

Comment: this middleware wouldn't be a global middleware since it wouldn't apply to all routes (there would still need to be a way to login) ... your middleware would also have to run after the session middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you can't register a middleware in both the global middleware array and the aliases array. That was the reason why Laravel couldn't use it correctly.